# Missing analysis service when creating new project

Tags: ssas, analysisservices

I have installed SSAS and created a project. After two months working with seas, now when creating a new project, the analysis service is not available. but I can open old SSAS projects. How I can create another new SSAS project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visual Studio (Open as Admin):
- Go to "Tools" >> "Extensions and Updates..."
- In the left pane, click on "Online"
- In the Search box on the top right enter "SSDT"
- check if the Extension "Microsoft Analysis Services Projects" is installed

[image]

In case it is installed and you still cannot choose Analysis Services as New Projects, you need to un-install the Extension and follow the instructions on the following website and install SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

**Visual Studio 2019:** Install Extension "Microsoft Analysis Services Projects"

**Visual Studio 2017:** Either install Extension, if that doesn't work for you, intall SSDT with the standalone installer: [Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.4)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2124518)

**Visual Studio 2015 and earlier:** Install via SSDT standalone installer required

It depends on which version of Visual Studio you are using. In 2015 everything needed to be installed via the standalone installer SSDT. In 2017 both the standalone installer and extensions exist, whereas in 2019 the standalone installer got replaced by the extensions. The super confusing part is, that there is the option to install "SSDT" during the installation of Visual Studio. Unfortunately installing SSDT during installing Visual Studio does not include Analysis/Reporting/ Integration Services.

Comment: Very frustrating ... freakin' microsoft. One day the Analysis Services were there in the list of new project types, then it was gone. Turns out it had been disabled ... but I didn't disable it, so go figure.